# How to chain action observables to emit synchronously and then emit a final value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I have a method that takes an observable as a parameter and returns another observable (if you're up to speed on Redux-Observable, it's has this type signature `function (action$: Observable<Action>): Observable<Action>;`

Within that method, I need the observable to do the following when it receives a `'POST_AND_GET_REQUEST'` action:

1. Uses the payload part of the action to synchronously perform a POST request for each object in an array
2. Once those synchronous calls are complete, perform a GET request
3. When the GET request returns a response, then return a `'POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS'` action

I've created a stackblitz to illustrate what I have so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-a2pwb8?file=index.ts

But here's the code snippet as well:

```
import { from, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, delay, mapTo, mergeMap, concatMap, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// GOAL
// synchronously post each period, when that's finished perform a get request
// postPeriods should only console the final POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS string that all was successful

interface ActionModel {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}

const postPeriods = (action$: Observable<ActionModel>) => action$.pipe(
  filter(action => action.type === 'POST_AND_GET_REQUEST'),
  mergeMap(action =>
    from(action.payload).pipe(
      concatMap(period => of(`${period} post success`).pipe(
        delay(1000),
        tap(() => console.log(`${period} post success`)),
        // this is wrong - we only want this to emit once
        switchMap(response => of('get success').pipe(map => of('POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS')))
      ))
    ),
  )
);

const postRequestAction = from([{ type: 'POST_AND_GET_REQUEST', payload: ['period 1', 'period 2'] }]);

// this should be a single 'POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS'
postPeriods(postRequestAction).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I know that where I have the `switchMap` is wrong, but I can't figure out how to chain off of the `from` observable or the `mergeMap` operator to get the result I want.

Comment: Hmm.. You are saying that the actions within the switchMap statement should only be carried out only after both items in the payload are completed?

Comment: @wentjun yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `postPeriod` epic, I would recommend you to end the action by returning a single observable, rather than returning multiple observables.

First, you may define an array (`observableList`), which will consists of a list of observables. Then, you may push the array with the observables from the `delayed`. Last but not least, you move the `switchMap()` logic such that it will only be carried out when  `observableList` is returned.

This will ensure that the `'get success'` action will only be carried out once, after the requests are completed, and the observables are returned.

```
import { from, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, delay, mapTo, mergeMap, concatMap, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// GOAL
// synchronously post each period, when that's finished perform a get request
// postPeriods should only console the final POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS string that all was successful

interface ActionModel {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}

const postPeriods = (action$: Observable<ActionModel>) => action$.pipe(
  filter(action => action.type === 'POST_AND_GET_REQUEST'),
  mergeMap(action => {
    // replace the generics with a suitable typing
    const observableList: Observable<any>[] = [];

    const delayed = from(action.payload).pipe(
      concatMap(period => of(`${period} post success`)
        .pipe(
          delay(1000),
          tap(() => console.log(`${period} post success`)),
        )),
    )
    observableList.push(delayed);

    return observableList;
  }),
  switchMap(response => of('get success').pipe(map => of('POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS')))
);

const postRequestAction = from([{ type: 'POST_AND_GET_REQUEST', payload: ['period 1', 'period 2'] }]);

// this should be a single 'POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS'
postPeriods(postRequestAction).subscribe(val => {
  console.log('end:', val);
});
```

Comment: Good thought here, but I think the problem with this approach is that the inner observables will never get subscribed too if you put them in an array and return it. When I plug it into the stackblitz, I see the POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS, but none of the console.logs from the tap, which I would expect to see as well as that single last POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS.

Answer (score 0):

If the GET request doesn't need any data from the responses of the post requests before, you could use `concat` to add the get action at the end

```
...
mergeMap(action =>
  concat(
    from(action.payload).pipe(
      concatMap(period => of(`${period} post success`).pipe(
        delay(1000),
        tap(() => console.log(`${period} post success`)),
      ))
    ),
    of('get success').pipe(map => of('POST_AND_GET_SUCCESS'))
  )
)
...
```

Comment: this looks like what i want, but i'm getting an error when i plug it into the stackblitz:


Error: You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift.call(concat_1.concat.apply(void 0, [source].concat(observables))); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: Where did you import ‘concat’ from? It should be ‘rxjs’, not ‘rxjs/operators’!

Comment: oh my mistake, I was importing concat as a rxjs/operators when i needed to import it  from rxjs.

Comment: ha, yes just figured that out. This is very close - it's still consoling out the values from the concatMap when I take the tap out, but for my purposes that's fine. Thanks!